# django 1.8 tutorial part 6

Tags: django, namespaces

First off, I realize Django 1.8 is outdated but I'm required to learn it for a project. I got through the first five parts without any issues but when I try to link the stylesheet in part 6, my stylesheet isn't loading (there's no change in the page).

I've gone over the code several times and checked the namespacing of each folder and it should be working but I can't seem to find the problem. If anyone has gone through this tutorial and could shed some light on the issue, I'd really appreciate it.

Here's the code in mysite/polls/templates/polls/index.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' 
%}" />


{% if latest_question_list %}

    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ 
question.question_t\
ext }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And here's my stylesheet located at mysite/polls/static/polls/style.css:

```
li a {
   color: green;
}

body {
     background: white url("images/background.gif") no-repeat right 
bottom;
}
```

Comment: As it is your template will not render a complete HTML page.

Comment: The issue might be because of caching (browser or server). Did you try clearing site data?

Comment: Did you check your browser console logs to see if the css is loaded(status 200) on loading the static files

Comment: Thanks Harsh! I had tried clearing my cache in chrome and it hadn't fixed it, but I just restarted the local Django server and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the same issue, restarting the Django server fixed the problem.